# DestroyJavaVMスレッドについて

Tags: java

eclipse上で、スレッドを立てるJavaのプログラムをデバッグ実行したところ、DestroyJavaVMという、自分で立てたわけではないスレッドの存在を確認しました。

このDestroyJavaVMスレッドについて2点質問があります。

- このスレッドの役割は何か？
- このスレッドが実行しているソースコードを確認するにはどこを参照すればよいか？

以下にDestroyJavaVMスレッドの存在を確認した際のスクリーンショットを記載します。プログラムは、Windows 64bit向けのeclipse Lunaで実行しています。

[image: DestroyJavaVMスレッドが立ち上がるプログラム]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### このスレッドの役割は何か？

[DestroyJavaVM - 呼び出しAPI (Java Native Interface仕様)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#DestroyJavaVM)

> Java VMをアンロードし、そのリソースを回復します。
>
> どのスレッドでも、接続されているかどうかにかかわらず、この関数を呼び出すことができます。現在のスレッドが接続されている場合、VMは、現在のスレッドがデーモンでない唯一のユーザー・レベルJavaスレッドになるまで待機します。現在のスレッドが接続されていない場合は、VMが現在のスレッドを接続し、現在のスレッドがデーモンでない唯一のユーザー・レベルのスレッドになるまで待機します。

とのことなので、`JVM`内で動いているユーザースレッドが無くなるまで待機し、それが無くなると、`JVM`を破棄してリソースの回復を行うスレッドのようです。

#### このスレッドが実行しているソースコードを確認するにはどこを参照すればよいか？

多分、 http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/bin/java.c です。

```
/*
 * Always detach the main thread so that it appears to have ended when
 * the application's main method exits.  This will invoke the
 * uncaught exception handler machinery if main threw an
 * exception.  An uncaught exception handler cannot change the
 * launcher's return code except by calling System.exit.
 *
 * Wait for all non-daemon threads to end, then destroy the VM.
 * This will actually create a trivial new Java waiter thread
 * named "DestroyJavaVM", but this will be seen as a different
 * thread from the one that executed main, even though they are
 * the same C thread.  This allows mainThread.join() and
 * mainThread.isAlive() to work as expected.
 */
#define LEAVE() \
    do { \
        if ((*vm)->DetachCurrentThread(vm) != JNI_OK) { \
            JLI_ReportErrorMessage(JVM_ERROR2); \
            ret = 1; \
        } \
        if (JNI_TRUE) { \
            (*vm)->DestroyJavaVM(vm); \
            return ret; \
        } \
    } while (JNI_FALSE)
```